# How to add sample size text to facet_wraped hex plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add the total number of observations to my hex plot, which has been faceted using `facet_wrap`. But I either get sample number for each bin, or can't place the text on the plot due to the layout.

I tried using `group_by()` and `tally()` from the `dplyr` package to find values but could not plot them.

```
ggplot(data = chris.sale.total, aes(x = px, y = pz)) + 
  geom_hex() + 
  coord_fixed() + 
  strike.zone + 
  home.plate + 
  scale_fill_viridis() + 
  facet_wrap(~outcome) + 
  theme_grey()
```

[image: hex plot]

Comment: What if you added the number of observations to the facetting? Like this maybe: `chris.sale.total <- chris.sale.total %>% group_by(outcome) %>% mutate(outcome_observation = paste0(outcome," - ", n()," observations"))`and then use `facet_wrap(outcome_observation)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `group_by`and `tally` create a new data.frame.
Then add a `geom_label` to your plot.

```
chris.sale.tally <- chris.sale.total %>% group_by(outcome) %>% tally()
ggplot(data = chris.sale.total, aes(x = px, y = pz)) + 
  geom_hex() + 
  coord_fixed() + 
  strike.zone + 
  home.plate +
  geom_label(aes(label=paste('n=', n)), x=-4.25, y=5, vjust=0, hjust=0, data=chris.sale.tally) +
  scale_fill_viridis() + 
  facet_wrap(~outcome) + 
  theme_grey()
```